# Slow site after embed SoudCloud

Tags: html, performance, iframe, soundcloud

I am making a website for myself. I would like to share some of my music, so i thought a good idea would be to embed some (4) of my pieces from SoudCloud (https://soundcloud.com/user-265594845).

But i now noticed that the website became really much slower. It's like if it has to wait for the SoundCloud embeds to completly load before anything else is working (like the hover effects or even scroll or button clicks...).

Is this normal? Any way around it? I would love to know how to optimize it.

Thank you!   =)

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you. I think SoundCloud server is having issues. My embedded player keeps saying `waiting on soundclound.com`then shows this eror: `The server closed the connection without sending any data.`If I reload the page, it works OK. I sent them an email and will post answers here as soon as I hear from them.